# How to add location-aware browsing in website?

Tags: firefox, geolocation

If I open website http://www.reebok.com/ru-RU/search/?q=mens in firefox there will be popup asking me to share my location. Here is the link about it http://www.mozilla.org/en/firefox/geolocation/
How can I add this in my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the reebok site is using the HTML5 Geolocation API.

Try the code below and it should recreate the behaviour. The code is taken directly from this page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation.getCurrentPosition

```
  var options = {
     enableHighAccuracy: true,
     timeout: 5000,
     maximumAge: 0
  };

  function success(pos) {
     var crd = pos.coords;

     console.log('Your current position is:');
     console.log('Latitude : ' + crd.latitude);
     console.log('Longitude: ' + crd.longitude);
     console.log('More or less ' + crd.accuracy + ' meters.');
  };

 function error(err) {
     console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
 };

 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```